# R: Reduce function. Na treatment

Tags: r, list, na

I have a question regarding the `Reduce`function.
For example i have a list that one of the elements has an `NA`.

```
a<-list(c(1,2),c(2,2),c(1,NA))
```

I wish to use the `Reduce` function to do an average of the elements of the list.

that is `(1+2+1)/3=1.33` and `(2+2+NA)/3 = NA` But in this last case, what i actually need is to avoid having the NA so the result should be `(2+2)/2 = 2`so the final outcome is a vector `1.33, 2`

I am using `Reduce("+", a)/length(a)` but i get an `NA` because of the NA element.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you do want to use `Reduce` try: `Reduce("+", lapply(a, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0))) / Reduce("+", lapply(a, Negate(is.na)))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wouldn't use `Reduce` for this. It is just a hidden `for` loop anyway. Here is a better alternative:

```
rowMeans(do.call(cbind, a), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 1.333333 2.000000
```

This combines your vectors into a matrix and calculates the row means using the `rowMeans` function, which can remove `NA` values.